# Getting an exception from MSVC address sanitizer before even entering WinMain

Tags: visual-c++, address-sanitizer

I wanted to try out the new address sanitizer for MSVC, and after enabling it in my project I'm getting an access violation exception which the call stack says originates in       `__acrt_initialize()` Line 291. Some research show that this happens before calling the main function, and indeed, a breakpoint on the first line of WinMain is not reached before this happens. With the sanitizer disabled, I am not getting any exceptions.

Comment: There's a problem in a constructor or initializer of some global variable. Perhaps an instance of [the static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof), where initialization of one global variable depends on another that's defined in a different translation unit.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that could be it, but all of my globals are POD. Any way to narrow it down to find the culprit?

Comment: Do you use libraries in DLLs that use the same C runtime and share some classes with the app? If so, maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/q/69678689/2945027